# Weatherproof enclosures IP65 or Nema 3R, with specific holes, 150x150mm?

Tags: enclosure

I'm needing an enclosure weatherproof and with dimensions around 150x150mm. 
After searching, I know that I should look for something like IP65 or higher, is this right?
I also want to have holes for an antenna, and a power suply cable, all this ofcourse weatherproof? Are all the enclosures in OKW ready with holes?How can I make sure the right holes are there before buying the cases?

thanks

Comment: What does "Weatherproof" mean for your application?  If it's just a point that your sales team wants on the datasheet, yes, IP65 will be fine.  If "Weatherproof" means that it might sit in a puddle for a few minutes, you are concerned about quality and want it to actually be watertight/weatherproof, or it's for safety-critical applications, then you may want to revise your criteria based on [the liquid-tight definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code#Liquids.2C_second_digit).

Comment: Don't enclosures usually have three dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

For the enclosure, [Bud Industries](http://www.budind.com/sealed_plastic.php) makes a line of NEMA rated waterproof plastic enclosures. They vary in price from $10 to $50 from distributors like [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com) based on size and rating.

An example box that may fit your dimension requirements is the [NBB-10260](http://www.budind.com/pdf/hb10240.pdf) [(Digikey)](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/NBB-10260/377-1245-ND/428994). It even comes with a clear lid for reading LCD displays if you need to.
[image: bud ind box]

An option for getting cables out of a box that I have used in the past is a [Cable Gland](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/19000005180/1195-3041-ND/3181626).

[image: cable gland]
[image: cable gland example]

You simply drill the correct size hole in your enclosure and tighten the cable gland around your cable.  If you adhere to the datasheet dimensions, it can be waterproof and dustproof.

Comment: It's worth noting that using the cable-gland as pictured in the last image will not actually provide a seal. You can only run one cable through each gland, or you get the possibility of leaks through the gabs between the cables.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Good point!

Comment: I think NEMA 4/4x (and higher) enclosures lose their rating if you drill holes in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use an otter box, drill some holes for ports and use weather proof connections. More about your question regarding IPx ratings, a rating of IP6x prevents ingress of dust. The second digit is water ingress, a IPx4 - IPx6 should be sufficient for weather protection, IPx7 and up for submersion in water. So IP64 or greater, same goes for any ports or connections you intend to use.

*I found them, they are still available. [otterbox dry boxes](http://www.otterbox.com/waterproof-cases/waterproof-cases,default,sc.html)

[image]

Comment: What's an "otter box"?